# Print Nested Objects in 2D

Tags: c#, arrays, object, recursion

I have a list of objects with lists of child objects which also have lists of child objects, etc. Here is a simplification with objects A and H:

[image: Object Nesting]

I would like to print them out in a 2D array, like so:

[image: Pint Output]

But I keep getting this:

[image: Misaligned Printing]

I'm using recursion for the first time, so tracking which row I'm on for which nested level is difficult. The code I'm using is cluttered with a bunch of carve-outs, so I'm hesitant to post it.

Does anyone have some pseudo-code that could help me fix my alignment issues?

```
List<int> levelStart = new List<int>();
    List<int> levelEnd = new List<int>();
    int tempEnding = 0;

    public void propertyValues2(Object inv, object[,] dataTest)
    {
        Type objType = inv.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = inv.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            DisplayNameAttribute DNA = (DisplayNameAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
            object propValue = property.GetValue(inv, null);
            var elems = propValue as System.Collections.IList;
            if (exportAll == true || exportColumns.Contains(DNA.DisplayName))
            {
                if (elems != null && elems.Count != 0)
                {                        
                    foreach (var item in elems)
                    {
                        if (!item.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.String"))
                        {
                            levelStart.Add(levelStart[levelStart.Count-1]);
                            propertyValues2(item, dataTest);
                            levelStart.RemoveAt(levelStart.Count - 1);
                        }
                        else if (exportColumns.Contains(DNA.DisplayName) || exportAll == true)
                        {
                            int counter = tempEnding;
                            if (dataTest[tempEnding, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null)
                            {
                                //dataRow = level[0];
                                for (int di = tempEnding; dataTest[di, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null; di++)
                                {
                                    tempEnding = di+1;
                                }
                            }
                            dataTest[tempEnding, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] = item;
                            if (tempEnding > endingRow)
                            {
                                endingRow = tempEnding;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    tempEnding = levelStart[levelStart.Count-1];
                    //dataRow = level[0];//level[0]
                }
                else if (elems != null && elems.Count == 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                }
                else if (propValue != null && propValue.ToString() != "")
                {
                    //dataRow = level[0];//level[0]
                    //int counter = level[level.Count-1];
                    if(DNA.DisplayName == "Procedure" || DNA.DisplayName == "Revenue Code")
                    {
                        if (columnIDs.Keys.Contains("Procedure") && columnIDs.Keys.Contains("Revenue Code"))
                        {
                            for (int di = tempEnding; dataTest[di, columnIDs["Procedure"]] != null || dataTest[di, columnIDs["Revenue Code"]] != null; di++)
                            {
                                tempEnding++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataTest[tempEnding, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null)
                    {
                        for (int di = tempEnding; dataTest[di, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null; di++)
                        {
                            tempEnding++;
                        }
                    }
                    dataTest[tempEnding, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] = propValue.ToString();
                    if (tempEnding > endingRow)
                    {
                        endingRow = tempEnding;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (elems != null && elems.Count != 0)
            {
                levelStart.Add(levelStart[levelStart.Count - 1]);
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    if (!item.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.String"))
                    {
                        propertyValues2(item, dataTest);
                    }
                    else if (exportColumns.Contains(DNA.DisplayName) || exportAll == true)
                    {
                        int counter = levelStart[levelStart.Count - 1];
                        if (dataTest[counter, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null)//level[level.Count - 1]
                        {
                            for (int di = levelStart[0]; dataTest[di, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null; di++)
                            {
                                counter++;//level[level.Count - 1]
                            }
                        }
                        dataTest[counter, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] = item;//level[level.Count - 1]
                        if (endingRow < counter)
                        {
                            endingRow = counter;
                        }
                    }
                    levelStart[levelStart.Count - 1] = endingRow + 1;
                }
                levelStart.RemoveAt(levelStart.Count - 1);
            }
        }
        foreach (string columnToCopy in columnsToCopy)
        {
            if (exportColumns.Contains(columnToCopy) || exportAll == true)
            {
                for (int i = levelStart[0] + 1; i <= endingRow; i++)//level[0]
                {
                    dataTest[i, columnIDs[columnToCopy]] = dataTest[i - 1, columnIDs[columnToCopy]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Array Structure:
[image: Array Structure]

Comment: are you printing this out in console?

Comment: Sending to Excel, but formatting in an array first (to make the translation to Excel happen quickly)

Comment: probably it's easier to write in dictionary

Comment: Weellll, I'm looping over dozens of string and list properties in thousands of objects and printing them all to a table, so I'm not sure a dictionary would work.

Comment: can you show me your arrays?

Comment: Posted the code sample - Array is dataTest[]

Comment: im still confused with your array structure. can you show data that will pass to dataTest ? what is the structure of multi nested array? Is it like this **[A,[B,[D,E]]],[A,[C,[F,G]]]** If this is the structure, I think there is not much we can do because it is correct.

Comment: Ok, I added the array structure to the post. Does that help?

Comment: Simplify the problem. (1) Create some initialization that sets up data exactly like that in the first image in the program. (2) Modify the code to use that data, rather than doing all the complicated stuff in your code. (3) Modify the code to be a compete program that we can run and test. (4) When that code works, write some more code that extracts the data from its original location and writes it into the data structures created for step (1).

Comment: Yes, I'm going to give this a try today. I'm going to define the variables I want to keep track of, create the loop/recursion structure, apply the variables, test, and then try to transpose it into the complicated stuff, above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I worked on yesterday. It seems to work in my test runs, but I will continue testing today. It has too many row changes while printing for me to keep track of, so I'm not completely sure it always prints correctly:

```
    int startInvoice = 1;
    List<int> levelStart = new List<int> { 1 };
    List<int> levelEnd = new List<int> { 1 };
    List<int> maxWithinLevel = new List<int> { 0 };
    int depth = 0;

    public int propertyValues3(Object inv, object[,] dataTest)
    {
        //int maxWithinLevel = 0;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = inv.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            DisplayNameAttribute DNA = (DisplayNameAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
            object propValue = property.GetValue(inv, null);
            var elems = propValue as System.Collections.IList;
            //if its a list
            if (elems != null && elems.Count != 0)
            {
                levelStart.Add(levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]);
                levelEnd.Add(levelStart[levelStart.Count - 1]);
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    //if its a class
                    if (!item.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.String"))
                    {
                        depth++;
                        levelStart[levelStart.Count-1] = propertyValues3(item, dataTest);
                        depth--;
                        if (levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1] < levelStart[levelStart.Count - 1])
                        {
                            levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1] = levelStart[levelStart.Count - 1];
                        }
                    }
                    //if its a string
                    else
                    {
                        if (dataTest[levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1], columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null)
                        {
                            for (int i = levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]; dataTest[i, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null; i++)
                            {
                                levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1] = i + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        dataTest[levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1], columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] = item; //legit
                        if (levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1] > endingRow)//legit
                        {
                            endingRow = levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                levelStart.RemoveAt(levelStart.Count - 1);
                //if (!elems[0].GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.String"))
                if(depth>0)
                {
                    maxWithinLevel.Add(levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]);
                }
                levelEnd.RemoveAt(levelEnd.Count - 1);
            }
            //if elems is empty
            else if (elems != null && elems.Count == 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
            }
            //if it's not a list
            else if (propValue != null && propValue.ToString() != "")
            {
                //handle procedure/revcode
                if (DNA.DisplayName == "Procedure" || DNA.DisplayName == "Revenue Code")
                {
                    if (columnIDs.Keys.Contains("Procedure") && columnIDs.Keys.Contains("Revenue Code"))
                    {
                        for (int i = levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]; dataTest[i, columnIDs["Procedure"]] != null || dataTest[i, columnIDs["Revenue Code"]] != null; i++)
                        {
                            levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (dataTest[levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1], columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null)
                {
                    for (int i = levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]; dataTest[i, columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] != null; i++)//legit
                    {
                        levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1]++;
                    }
                }
                dataTest[levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1], columnIDs[DNA.DisplayName]] = propValue.ToString();//level[level.Count - 1]
                if (levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1] > endingRow)
                {
                    endingRow = levelEnd[levelEnd.Count - 1];
                }
            }
        }
        if (levelStart.Count==0 || levelStart.Max() < maxWithinLevel.Max())
        {
            return maxWithinLevel.Max() + 1;
        }
        else return levelStart.Max();
    }
```